# How to set the rule priority in Drools Decision table

Tags: drools

I need to specify the rules order of execution, I tried to specify the keyword  priority LHS to the first CONDITION keyword and define the priority as integer in the rule rows under the same column, but looks like this does not work. Please help me to set the priority in decision table.

[image: rules]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rule metadata called "salience " to set rule execution priority. Higher the , is higher the priority.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change value of SEQUENTIAL attribute from TRUE to FALSE as currently it is overwriting PRIORITY that you have set manually.